# Can an xlwings UDF return a list of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, excel, vba, numpy, xlwings

I am trying to write an *xlwings* user-defined function (UDF) which returns a list of *numpy* arrays in Excel VBA.  Is this possible?

Whenever I try, I get this error in VBA:

[image: image of my error]

In words, that's:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Unexpected Python Error: TypeError: Internal error - the buffer length is not the sequence length!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to return multiple Numpy arrays is to combine them into a single 2D array in Python and return that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be:  no, it is not possible.